# QuartzCore: Draw a shape with a hole in it?

Tags: objective-c, cgpath, quartz-core

How would one draw a shape with a hole in it using QuartzCore?

Here is an example:
[image]

I already understand how to draw a path:

```
CGMutablePathRef maskPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(maskPath, NULL, x1, y1);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(maskPath, NULL, x2, y2);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(maskPath, NULL, x3, y3);
CGPathCloseSubpath(maskPath);
```

and apply it to a UIView:

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = viewToMask.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath;
viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

but I am not entirely sure how I could create a path with a hole in the center.
Do I need to somehow subtract from the path, maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Graphics, how to draw a Rectangle with an ellipse transparency hole?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867300/core-graphics-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-an-ellipse-transparency-hole)

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers my question. Could someone elaborate on that answer here if it is the correct thing to do?

Comment: Could also be a duplicate of [Crop a CAShapeLayer retrieving the external path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10856353/608157) since the shape is being used to have a CAShapeLayer mask out the hole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are setting the CGPath as the path property of a CAShapeLayer to be the mask, you should look at [Crop a CAShapeLayer retrieving the external path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10856353/608157) and **[its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881680/608157)**.