# Remove a circle from a rectangle using Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-core

I am trying to remove a circle shape from a rectangle using core graphic. So that I can see through the circular hole (like a porthole)

I have searched extensively and tried to utilise the answer provided here [Core Graphics, how to draw a Rectangle with an ellipse transparency hole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867300/core-graphics-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-an-ellipse-transparency-hole) but I cannot get it to work. All I achieve in doing is drawing a circle on top of a rectangle. Here's the code I ended up with, thanks for any assistance

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// Set color to red
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
// Add rectange
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
// Fill rectange
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

// Create a elipse to be removed from rectange

CGMutablePathRef cutoutRect = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(cutoutRect, NULL, rect);
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(cutoutRect, NULL, CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width / 4, self.bounds.size.height / 4, self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.width / 2));

CGContextAddPath(context, cutoutRect);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextEOFillPath(context);

//Remove the elipse

CGContextEOClip(context);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using `CGContextEOFillPath` you need to add one path for the rectangle, and one path for the ellipse. Here the two shapes are mixed up in a single path, which doesn't work.

And BTW, your final `CGContextEOClip` call is useless.